# Why in RecyclerView findViewByPosition() returns null on EditText

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have an `Activity`, which has a `RecyclerView` and save `Button`. Each item (football match) of the `RecyclerView` contains some text (name of teams) and `EditText`, where user enters data (actually bet the match). My goal is to save those scores to the list in the `Activity`, when user clicked on save `Button`.

I implemented this method in `Activity`, which actually get particular item from `LinearLayoutManager` and then get data from `EditText`, but the `findViewByPosition()` method (or getChildAt() there are different way to do this) sometimes returns null.

I saw another answers on similar question, but they didn't help me. Maybe my strategy is wrong, because I made whole my logic in Activity (better to do this in Adapter?) and I get though all of my items in `RecyclerView` even if only in one user entered the score.

```java
    private List<Bet> getUserBets() {
        View betView;
        Bet betItem;
        EditText userBet1;
        EditText userBet2;

        int numberOfMatches = rvBetsAdapter.getItemCount();
        List<Bet> bets = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMatches; i++)
        {
            betItem = rvBetsAdapter.getItem(i);
            betView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(i); 
            userScore1 = (EditText) betView.findViewById(R.id.result1); // <- NPE appears
            userScore2 = (EditText) betView.findViewById(R.id.result2);
            //here i checked whether the editText is empty and other stuff
            bets.add(betItem);
        }
        return bets;
    }
```

How do I fix it? I suppose I should do something in onBindViewHolder method in my adapter, but what exactly? 
I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: add your stacktrace of the error to better understand the problem

Comment: Yes your approach is not perfect, ui logic of a view that is managed by recycler view should be handled in view holders that are managed by the adapter of the recycler view.

Comment: it is because you may be calling this for loop inside the onBindViewHolder of the adapter and you are initing the views each time onBindViewHolder is called and moreover, you are doing this inside the loop. From your code it looks like the situation. By the way you should use a viewholder instead and share some more adapter code

Comment: To communicate from Adapter of your Recyclerview to Activity/Fragment you need to add Interface and then notifyDataSetChanged to the adapter will refresh your list.

Comment: *Sometimes return null* because these items are not displaying on the screen. I think you should check it by using `findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` and `findLastVisibleItemPosition()` methods

Comment: @TouhidulIslam but the error is the simply nullPointerException on the line i marked

Comment: @JohnLe I can check it, but I should get information from those views, so if the betView is null I can do nothing about data inside.

Comment: @JavaNerd I use this method inside my Activity, so at this moment I use only betItem from my adapter, exactly - getItem method. My adapter looks like really default one, in viewHolder I made all of my findViewById stuff and in onBindViewHolder I set the default appearance of the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add to your `Bet` model variable which holds `EditText` value for example `editTextValue`.

And access it using list in adapter list like this end use `EditText` value from there. `rvBetsAdapter.getItem(i).editTextValue`

`editTextValue` can be set using `TextWatcher.afterTextChanged()` callback

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my problem. I just didn't know that something like ```TextWatcher``` exists. Also I have one additional questions:
**1.** In this loop (in method above) I traverse though all bets, but I want to traverse only thought all changed bets. So I consider making an ```Array``` in ```Adapter``` which contains position of bet item which was changed and in this loop get only those item which position are in that ```Array```. Is it a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can only find or get views that are visible on the screen.

before using `findViewByPosition(2)`
go to position 2 by `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(2);`

if you want to change value of this views, The best way is get your item in list

```
yourModel item = (yourModel) itemList.Get(2)
item.Name = "Edited";

yourAdapter.notifyItemChanged(2);
```

Comment: I don't want to change value of the view. I just want to get rid of my NPE. 
Firstly, scrollToPosition should be invoke on ```LinearLayoutManager```, not on ```RecyclerView```.
Secondly, it doesn't work